# bxslider no funciona con *ngFor en Angular10

Tags: nodejs, angular

Tengo un bxslider en mi proyecto que usaba con imagenes ya cargadas en mi assets mientras desarrollaba el backend tal que así:

```
<div class="galeria">
  <div><img src="/assets/img/1.jpg" title="Lorem Ipsum"></div>
  <div><img src="/assets/img/2.jpg" title="Lorem Ipsum"></div>
  <div><img src="/assets/img/3.jpg" title="Lorem Ipsum"></div>
  <div><img src="/assets/img/4.jpg" title="Lorem Ipsum"></div>
  <div><img src="/assets/img/5.jpg" title="Lorem Ipsum"></div>
</div>
```

En el componente tengo mi slider tal que así:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getSliderImagenes();
    this.cargarGaleria();
  }

cargarGaleria(){
    $('.galeria').bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
      captions: false,
      slideWidth:900,
      speed:700,
      infiniteLoop: true,
      auto: true,
      pager: true,
    });
}
```

El caso es, que ahora al obtener las imagenes de mi backend me salen las imagenes descuadradas (una debajo de otra, y la del medio con los botones del slider pero que no hacen nada)

Ahora tengo mi HTML tal que así:

```
<div class="galeria">
    <div *ngFor="let slider_images of slider"><img src="{{url+'get-image-slider/'+slider_images.imagen}}" *ngIf="slider_images.imagen"/></div>
  </div>
```

¿Cómo podría arreglarlo para poder usar el slider como antes?

Gracias de antemano

EDIT:

```
getSliderImagenes(){
    this._sliderImagesService.getSliderImagenes().subscribe(
      response =>{
        if(response.slider){
          this.slider = response.slider;
          this.cargarGaleria();
        }
      },err=>{
        console.log(<any>err)
      }
    )
  }
```

Llamando a la galería dentro de la petición para obtener las imagenes tampoco funciona.

EDIT2:

***BACKEND SLIDER ROUTES***

```
router.get('/get-slider', SliderController.getSlider);
router.get('/get-image-slider/:imagen', SliderController.getImagen);
```

***BACKEND SLIDER CONTROLLER***

```
getSlider: function (req, res) {
        Slider.find({}).exec((err, slider) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error al mostrar las imagenes del slider' });

            if (!slider) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'No existen imagenes para mostrar' });

            return res.status(200).send({
                slider: slider
            });
        })

    },



getImagen: function(req, res){
        var archivo = req.params.imagen;
        var path_archivo = './uploads/'+archivo;

        fs.exists(path_archivo, (exists)=>{
            if(exists){
                return res.sendFile(path.resolve(path_archivo));
            }else{
                return res.status(200).send({
                    message: "no existe la imagen..."
                })
            }
        })
    },
```

***FRONT*** SLIDER SERVICE:

```
getSliderImagenes():Observable<any>{
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application-json');
        return this._http.get(this.url+'get-slider', {headers:headers});
    }
```

Este es mi código completo. He intentado hacerlo como me dijiste pero no lo conseguí... Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Llama la función `this.cargarGaleria();` justo después de recibir los datos del backend ( debe removerse del constructor ):

```
this.slider = response.slider;
this.cargarGaleria();
```

No funciona con `*ngFor` porque las imágenes se descargan de forma asíncrona. Por esa razón cuando se llama el método `cargarGaleria()` la petición http todavía no ha finalizado y los elementos html no han sido creados con el `*ngFor`.

**Actualización:**

Agrega un timeout para hacer una pequeña espera mientras se renderizan los elementos html:

```
this.slider = response.slider;
setTimeout(()=>{ this.cargarGaleria() },10);
```

**Ejemplo completo**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

declare var $ : any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
        <div class="galeria">
            <div *ngFor="let img of images"><img src="{{img}}" ></div>
        </div>
              `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  images= [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.loadImages();
  }

  loadImages(){
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
    .subscribe((response : any[]) => {
      
          this.images = response.map( r => r.url).slice(0,10);

          setTimeout(()=> this.cargarGaleria(),10);
    });
  }


cargarGaleria(){
    $('.galeria').bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
      captions: false,
      slideWidth:900,
      speed:700,
      infiniteLoop: true,
      auto: true,
      pager: true,
    });
}
}
```

[Demo en vivo Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3nyjyg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hola @Lobos, he probado como me dijiste pero no funcionó. Retire el cargarGaleria del ngOnInit y lo puse dentro del métdo de getsliderimagenes() , revisa en la edicion del post

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Lobos, al intentar meterlo después del if las imagenes simplemente no cargan (EDIT: metí una espera un poco mayor de 0.5seg y si cargan, pero me pasa lo mismo que poniendolo antes del if, carga siempre la primera imagen), y al meterlo antes del if, en la response carga el slider perfectamente con todos los elementos pero siempre reproduce la primera imagen

Comment: de todas formas, tras recargar  varias veces la pagina a veces ni cargan..

Comment: Solo quiero aclarar una duda ya que veo que mencionas meterlo  antes y después del if. La línea `setTimeout(()=>{ this.cargarGaleria() },10);` la has puesto así como en el ejemplo, justo después de `this.slider = response.slider;` ? O sea dentro del if.

Comment: si, correcto, por qué?

Comment: Agregué un ejemplo completo.

Comment: Hola de nuevo @Lobos, disculpa. Acabo de probar el ejemplo y me ha funcionado correctamente. Pero con mi código no soy capaz de sacarlo... Te agrego los métodos que uso desde el backend y los servicios. Gracias

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113619/discussion-between-lobos-and-adromicfms).

Comment: podes fijarte también, haciendo el llamado a this.cargarGaleria() en el método finally del subscribe, así no deberías tener que usar el timeout que no esta muy bueno.

Comment: Hola @Cribelo al fin pude solucionarlo mezclando la soluciones de usted y Lobos dentro del .add del subscribe, llamé al metodo de cargar la galería con un timeout. Muchas gracias

Comment: Si claro, estaría solucionado, pero que pasa si pones un timeout de 5 segundos y por x motivos la carga tarda 6 segundos?

Comment: @Cribelo el timeout es solo para darle tiempo al framework de renderizar los elementos html antes de inicializar el slider. No está ahí para esperar que la petición finalice.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUCIONADO. Gracias a @Lobos y @Cribelos.

```
getSliderImagenes(){
    this._sliderImagesService.getSliderImagenes().subscribe(
      response =>{
        if(response.slider){
          
          this.slider = response.slider;
        }
        
      },err=>{
        console.log(<any>err)
      }
    ).add(()=>{
      setTimeout(()=>{ this.cargarGaleria() },10);
    });
  }
```

Solo había que llamar al método con un pequeño timeOut dentro de ADD esperando que ya haya finalizado la carga.